# Convert select multiple input into array of boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best approach getting an array of Boolean that represent if the option is selected or not?

### For Example:

When the markup is:

```
<select id="myMultipleSelect" multiple>
    <option selected>Urgent</option>
    <option selected>Important</option>
    <option selected>Other</option>
</select>
```

The desired result array should be structured as:

- **All** options are selected: `[true,true,true]`.
- **Urgent** option only is selected: `[true,false,false]`.
- **Urgent**, **Important** options are selected: `[true,true,false]`.

---

I've tried working with $.val() but it returns (when all option are selected) `["Urgent","Important","Other"]` or for **Urgent** option only is selected it returns: `["Urgent"]`

```
$('#myMultipleSelect').on('change', event => {               
    console.log($(event.currentTarget).val());
});
```

Is there any elegant way achieving this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of jQuery [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

- `$('option',this)` selects every `option` from your `select`
- `.get()` returns the Javascript DOM elements from a jQuery selector
- `.map()` goes through your array
- `$(e).is(':selected')` returns `true` or `false` if your option is selected or not

```js
$('#myMultipleSelect').on('change', function(){               
    console.log($('option',this).get().map(e => $(e).is(':selected')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myMultipleSelect" multiple>
    <option selected>Urgent</option>
    <option selected>Important</option>
    <option selected>Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like the following:

```js
$('#myMultipleSelect').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $.map($(this).children('option'), function(opt) {
    return $(opt).prop('selected') === true;
  });

  console.log(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myMultipleSelect" multiple>
    <option selected>Urgent</option>
    <option selected>Important</option>
    <option selected>Other</option>
</select>
```

It listens to the change event of the dropdown, and then traverses its `option` tags to map their `selected` property.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<select id="myMultipleSelect" multiple>
    <option selected value='Urgent'>Urgent</option>
    <option selected value='Important'>Important</option>
    <option selected value='Other'>Other</option>
</select>
<button type='button' onclick='getValue()'>Get value</button>  
  <script>
  function getValue()
  {
  var array;
  var value = $("#myMultipleSelect").val();
  debugger;
  
  if (~value.indexOf("Urgent") && ~value.indexOf("Important") && ~value.indexOf("Other")){
array = [true,true,true];
}

else if (~value.indexOf("Urgent") && !~value.indexOf("Important") && !~value.indexOf("Other")){
array = [true,false,false];
}

else if (~value.indexOf("Urgent") && ~value.indexOf("Important") && !~value.indexOf("Other")){
array = [true,true,false];
}

alert(array);


  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP asked for an elegant way to do this. That ... not what I'd call elegant.